# Rhythmbox keeps crashing on start

Tags: release-freya, apps

in my system, I can't open rhythmbox. It crash as soon as I start it! How can I fix this? I'm running the latest Freya.

Terminal output :

```
(rhythmbox:16154): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_css_provider_load_from_path: assertion 'path != NULL' failed
Unable to open ~/.mtpz-data for reading, MTPZ disabled.
(rhythmbox:16154): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: object SoupServer 0x24802a0 finalized while still in-construction

(rhythmbox:16154): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: Custom constructor for class SoupServer returned NULL (which is invalid). Please use GInitable instead.

(rhythmbox:16154): Gtk-WARNING **: Duplicate child name in GtkStack: Add to Playlist


(rhythmbox:16154): Gtk-WARNING **: Duplicate child name in GtkStack: Add to Playlist


(rhythmbox:16154): Gtk-WARNING **: Duplicate child name in GtkStack: Add to Playlist


(rhythmbox:16154): Gtk-WARNING **: Duplicate child name in GtkStack: Add to Playlist


(rhythmbox:16154): Gtk-WARNING **: Duplicate child name in GtkStack: Add to Playlist


(rhythmbox:16154): Gtk-WARNING **: Duplicate child name in GtkStack: Add to Playlist

[1]    16154 segmentation fault (core dumped)  rhythmbox
```

Comment: Can you try running it via the terminal? Often it shows warnings and/or errors that may be useful to see what's going on.

Comment: Got a segmentation fault! After purging everything, resetting gsettings, removing cache dirs it didnt work. Did it several times and finally it worked.

Comment: @ThiagoJedi After restarting it happened again!